# Decimal.Parse Issue

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal, cultureinfo

I have a problem with decimal parse, I know this question been asked a loot, but none of the solution worked for me, and i've been stuck in here for two days now.

My problem is my CultureInfo is set to  fr_Fr and  when i put the code below an error shows caused with comma that separates decimal instead of period.

```
double entree = Convert.ToDouble(row["entree"]);
double sortie = Convert.ToDouble(row["sortie"]);
int id_mw = Convert.ToInt32(row["mouvment_w_id"]);

qte_Stock += entree - sortie;
decimal qte_s ;

MessageBox.Show("" + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
qte_s = Decimal.Parse(Convert.ToString(qte_Stock), NumberStyles.Number ^ NumberStyles.AllowThousands);

MessageBox.Show("" + qte_s);
qte.CommandText = "Update tcpos.dbo.Warehouse_mouvement set qte_stock= " + qte_s + " where mouvment_w_id = "+id_mw;
qte.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you xor-ing the two `NumberStyles` together?

Comment: Side note - please don't construct SQL queries by string concatenation. Please use parameters (this could also avoid your issue, since that way you never treat the decimal as a string either)

Comment: What's the type of `qte_Stock`, and why are you converting it to a string before then converting to decimal? Why go via a string? Additionally, **please** use parameterized SQL instead of embedding values directly into your SQL.

Comment: Shouldn't it be  NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowThousands ? Why from double via string to decimal?

Comment: Why are you converting a double(?) to decimal via a string? Is there something special you are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I only converted it to a string to use Decimal.Parse

Comment: @SKGeek: Ok, but what was it before, a decimal?

Comment: The error get fired every time the debugger reached the update statement because of the comma that just doesn't want to get change or removed

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes it was a decimal

Comment: @SKGeek: Then you have your answer since you want to make it a decimal. Do nothing and it works (two days for nothing).

Comment: I tried that in the first place , but the comma fired the exception that why i been trying everything and anything and till didn't work

Comment: @SKGeek: Use `Parameters` as Jon already has suggested. That will prevent you from sql-injection and this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the type of qte_Stock

...

> it was a decimal

...

> Then you have your answer since you want to make it a decimal.

Pass the decimal as [`Parameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) to prevent sql-injection and this issue(decimal separator).

For example(assuming SQL-Server as rdbms):

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("Update tcpos.dbo.Warehouse_mouvement set qte_stock=@qte_stock where mouvment_w_id = @mouvment_w_id", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qte_stock", qte_stock);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mouvment_w_id", id_mw);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
qte_s = qte_Stock.ToString ("#.#", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will solve, if your problem is because in your culture (like mine), the comma seaparates decimals, and not thousands.

Also, use parameterized SQL, like  Damien_The_Unbeliever and Jonh Skeet said.